# m.find() returns false when it should return true

Tags: java, regex

`m.find()` returns false when it should return true.

`solrQueries[i]` contains the string:

```
"fl=trending:0,id,business_attr,newarrivals:0,bestprice:0,score,mostviewed:0,primarySortOrder,fastselling:0,modelNumber&defType=pedismax&pf=&mm=2<70%&bgids=1524&bgboost=0.1&shards.tolerant=true&stats=true"
```

The code is:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("&mm=(\\d+)&");
for(int i=0; i<solrQueries.length; i++) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(solrQueries[i].toLowerCase());
    System.out.println(p.matcher(solrQueries[i].toLowerCase()));
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        mmValues[i] = m.group(1);
    }
```

Comment: And what are the input strings? (See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )

Comment: what exactly does `solrQueries[i]` contain?

Comment: It does not have to be true that m.find() should return true. Without the text you feed the engine with we cannot help you. The pattern itself is valid and matches `&mm=`, then captures 1+ digits into Group 1, and then matches `&`. Are you sure you need the `&` at the end? Are you sure the input contains `&` and not `&amp;`? Maybe you want to match at the end of the string? Then the last `&` must be replaced with `(?:&|$)`

Comment: solrQueries[i]:
fl=trending:0,id,business_attr,newarrivals:0,bestprice:0,score,mostviewed:0,primarySortOrder,fastselling:0,modelNumber&defType=pedismax&pf=&mm=2<70%&bgids=1524&bgboost=0.1&shards.tolerant=true&stats=true&requestId=330076122136444&nanoTime=3736784491603538&shards=http://20.0.0.58:5050/solr/pog,http://20.0.0.58:7070/solr/pog,http://20.0.0.58:9090/solr/pog&qt=/customSelect&qf=tag_aggr upc^5 discLabel^1 disclabel_ph^1 name^1 name_split^1 tokenizedBrand^1 supc^5 supc_split^5 b_isbn13 b_isbn10 b_author b_publisher b_genre metadataList^0.2

Comment: So, remove the `&` at the  end: `"&mm=(\\d+)"`

Comment: Tried, m.find() is still false

Comment: Good, and if you use `"&(?:amp;)?mm=(\\d+)"`?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Wiktor, m.find() prints true when I'm printing its value, however, if block isn't executed yet, seems strange.

Comment: @Sebastian, sure, will keep in mind

Comment: What block is not executed? Do you try to check the `m` value *before* `m.find()`? Is your code different from what you posted? I am sure you have different code, or doing something you did not mention in the question.

Comment: @VedikaHansaria don't keep it in mind - do so. One should be able to paste the code you posted into ones IDE, press run and see the same results as you did. You can edit your post any time if you want to add missing information.

Comment: m :
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=&(?:amp;)?mm=(\d+) region=0,938 lastmatch=],    if(m.find()) {...}
isn't being executed

Comment: See http://ideone.com/N4CbDB. Comment out that println line with the matcher as you do not need it (it just shows the matcher, but does not actually run it, you do not get matches this way), and remove the trailing `&`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, please have a look at the screenshot attached

Comment: So, your code **is** different. You executed `m.find()` twice. And since there is only 1 match - even if the regex matches  - you would get nothing after the second run.

Answer (score 1):

Oh,

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)&mm=(\d+)");

works fine now.

Thank you, @Wiktor Stribiżew

Answer (score 0):

You executed `m.find()` twice (first, in `System.out.println(m.find());` and then in `if (m.find())`). And since there is only 1 match - even if the regex matches - you would get nothing after the second run.

Use

```
public String[] fetchMmValue(String[] solrQueries) {
    String[] mmValues = new String[solrQueries.length];
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)&mm=(\\d+)");
    for(int i=0; i<solrQueries.length; i++) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(solrQueries[i]);
        if (m.find()) {
        // System.out.println(m.group(1)); // this is just for debugging
        mmValues[i] = m.group(1);
    }
    return mmValues;
}
```

If you want to get all chars other than `&` after `&mm=`, use another regex:

```
"&mm=([^&]+)"
```

where `[^&]+` matches 1 or more chars other than `&`.